# How to turn on notifications about new message on Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-messenger

I just started with creating my own page on Facebook. How to turn on notifications, when someone send me a new message via FB page?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear so these official pages will help you find your answer.

- [How do I turn Messenger notifications on or off?](https://www.facebook.com/help/330627630326605)
- [How do I choose which Facebook notifications I want to get as text messages (SMS)?](https://www.facebook.com/help/111970308891187)
- [How do I change my notification settings for a Page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/172901342767609)
- [How do I adjust my email notifications from Facebook?](https://www.facebook.com/help/154884887910599)
- [Choose What You're Notified About](https://www.facebook.com/help/269880466696699/?helpref=hc_fnav)
- [Push, Email and Text Notifications](https://www.facebook.com/help/530847210446227/?helpref=hc_fnav)
- [Notifications](https://www.facebook.com/help/1036755649750898/?helpref=hc_fnav)

***You can also search this site by clicking [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfacebook%5D+notifications) (tag `facebook`, search menu `notifications`)***

Comment: More than a month has passed, and the "Suggest Edits" option is missing in several pages as showin in the screenshot below. So, I am reporting the issue here.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgpPz.jpg